# Nuxt, accessing vuex store in router.js (@nuxt/router)

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

Using the @nuxt/router module I have a router.js with my routes and I want to do some stuff in router.beforeEach... which is dependent on state values in different store modules.

My store folder looks like this:
index.js, auth.js, language.js  ...

New to Nuxt, I have trouble understanding how to make the store accessible in this route file.
I get errors when I try to import it, do I need to inject the context ? is the context already available ?
Change the store set-up and export it ? Use middleware ?

I mananged to get partly there with
`import {state} from '@/store/language'`
and then getting a value with `state().activeLang` but this value doesn't update when the store value changes, and a single import only covers part of the need.

My router.js file looks like this:

````
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import Home from '@/views/Home/Home'
import Admin from '@/views/Admin/Admin'

Vue.use(Router)

//do I need to pass the context into this function ???

export function createRouter() {
  const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
      { path: '/', component: Home, name: 'home' },
      { path: '/admin', component: Admin, name: 'admin' },
    ]
  })

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

   // do stuff here...
   // e.g. check auth store if user is authenticated
   // e.g. get active language from language store

    return next();
  });

  return router
}```
````

Comment: It seems that beforeEach can be handled through middleware by making {app} available in the function and then  having app.router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => ....)  Generally that's OK with the only drawback that middleware is not called on the client on inital page load, but that is how nuxt does it right now...I'm still curious if there is a way to do all this in the router.js, because one of my aims is to localize route paths and for that having access to the declared routes is important.